# yii2 gridView shows only unique rows

Tags: mysql, gridview, yii2

I use related models `author` and `book`, and try to show it by `gridWiev widget`,
all is alright, but somehow only unique rows displayed.
Despite the query is ok, and return me all rows.

```
SELECT `book`., `author`. FROM `book` LEFT JOIN `author` ON `book`.`author` = `author`.`id` LIMIT 20
```

This query return 4 rows, but in gridview only 2, why?
I hope someone helps me, thank you in advance.

Code is here https://github.com/underpantsGnomes/test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened becouse column `id` has the same name.
I just rename author.`id` to author.`idAuthor` and all worked.

Comment: I had the same problem and conflicting `id` columns which GridView uses to render the rows was the reason. Another potential solution to overcome this is to set a custom `indexBy` value with a function: `$query->indexBy(function($row){ return $row['id'].'-'.$row['book_id']; });` but you need to explicitly add `book_id` to the select.